# Using SetTimeOut to fadeout a list of element tiling on each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Suppose that I have a list of elements tiling on each other using z-index. For example:

```
<div id="lyrics">
   <div class="lyric" style="z-index: 1000" val="2000">This is the first sentence</div>
   <div class="lyric" style="z-index: 100" val="2000">Second sentence is here</div>
   <div class="lyric" style="z-index: 10" val="0">And the third one</div>
</div>
```

Now I want to do this animation in which using jQuery to make the first lyric disappear (opacity goes to 0) in 2000ms, and then the next one, and so on until nothing left.

The problem is, with this code below, it seems like all lyric elements vanish at once.

```
function sto(varx, delay) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        varx.fadeOut("fast");
    }, delay);
}

$(".lyric").each(function(){
    var delay = $(this).attr("val");
    sto($(this), 2000);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting them all the start fading out in 2 seconds so they all go at once.  To make one go after the other, you either need to set incrementing timeouts where each one is set to a time after the previous one or make it so the next animation starts when the first one completes and so on.

Here's a way with accumulating timers where you've set the `val` attribute on each item to the proper accumulated delay for each item:

```
$(".lyric").each(function(){
    var item = $(this);
    item.delay(item.attr("val")).fadeOut("fast");
});
```

Here's a way using completion functions to chain them one after the other where you set the `val` attribute to the delay before fading this item (not the cumulative delay):

```
(function() {
    var items = $(".lyric");
    var index = 0;

    function next() {
        if (index < items.length) {
            var item = items.eq(index++);
            item.delay(item.attr("val")).fadeOut("fast", next);
        }
    }
    next();
})();
```

In both examples, note you can use `.delay()` with all jQuery animations rather than set your own `setTimeout()`.

Also, note that you should be using `data-val="2000"` and then `.data("val")` to read it to be HTML5 compliant.

Answer (score 2):

You are not passing the delay values. Try this:

HTML:

```
<div id="lyrics">
   <div class="lyric" style="z-index: 1000" val="2000">This is the first sentence</div>
   <div class="lyric" style="z-index: 100" val="1000">Second sentence is here</div>
   <div class="lyric" style="z-index: 10" val="500">And the third one</div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function sto(varx, delay) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        varx.fadeOut("fast");
    }, delay);
}

$(".lyric").each(function(){
    var delay = $(this).attr("val");
    sto($(this), delay);
});
```

I have changed values so that you can see animations
Here is the working [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/2HcGZ/3/)